# multiple dependency in checkboxpreference android

Tags: android, dependencies, checkboxpreference

i have three checkboxes in my preference screen. i want to make the user select only one checkbox at a time.
How do i achieve this?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create an onpreferenceChangelistener:

```
prefChangeListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    if (preference == pref1 && newValue.toString().equals("true")){
                        pref2.setChecked(false);
                        pref3.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    if (preference == pref2 && newValue.toString().equals("true")){
                        pref1.setChecked(false);
                        pref3.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    if (preference == pref3 && newValue.toString().equals("true")){
                        pref1.setChecked(false);
                        pref2.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    return true;    
                }
        };
```

Then to use it,

```
pref1.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(prefChangeListener);
pref2.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(prefChangeListener);
pref3.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(prefChangeListener);
```

Or, you can use a ListPreference which will pop up a radio group and you can just put the three option in there. That's what I did in my App, but If the checkboxpreferences are needed, then that of course will work.

Here's my listpreference (for choosing how long it will ring for):

```
<ListPreference android:persistent="true"
            android:title="Ring Time"
            android:summary="Choose how long the phone will ring when activated"
            android:key="ringTime"
            android:defaultValue="ringNot"
            android:entries="@array/ringTime"
            android:entryValues="@array/ringSetting" />
```

And here's my XML for the @array/ringTime and @array/ringSetting

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="ringTime">
   <item>Don\'t Ring</item>
   <item>Ring 30 Seconds</item>
   <item>Ring 2 Minutes</item>   
   <item>Ring 5 Minutes</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="ringSetting">
   <item>ringNot</item>
   <item>ring30Sec</item>
   <item>ring2Min</item>   
   <item>ring5Min</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

I know this is a 5-month old question as of today, but I thought this might help someone else. :)

And then for implementing the listpreference inside my code:

```
ringTime = pref.getString("ringTime", "ringNot");//ListPreferences are stored as strings
if (ringTime.equals(ring30Sec))
//ring for 30 seconds
else if (ringTime.equals(ring2Min))
//ring for 2 minutes
else if (ringTime.equals(ring5Min))
//ring for 5 minutes
else Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Not Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

[That is called a radio button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html). Youre welcome

Comment: unfortunately, on preference screen ,there is not such radio preference available. i will have to work with checkboxpreference.

Comment: Can you share the code of your preference screen and a screenshot. I see no reason why you can't use the Radio Group

Comment: here is my code.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <CheckBoxPreference android:key="english"
  android:title="English" android:defaultValue="true"></CheckBoxPreference>
 <CheckBoxPreference android:key="german"
  android:title="German" android:defaultValue="false"></CheckBoxPreference>
 <CheckBoxPreference android:key="netherlands"
  android:title="Dutch" android:defaultValue="false"></CheckBoxPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>

Comment: You should use a [ListPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html) [instead](http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences)

Answer (score 0):

using radio group maybe? :)
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#RadioButtons

or if you really need to use checkbox widget, you could check other checkboxes using isChecked() and untick then via setChecked(false) in your OnCheckedChangeListener class implementation

Comment: how do you use radio button on preference screen?

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    //mSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mLocationChangedListener = new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                Object newValue) {
            mChbLocationLastChanged = (CheckBoxPreference) preference;
            return true;
        }

    };
    mLocationClickListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            setLocationAccuracy();
            return true;
        }
    };
    mChbLocationHigh = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("pref_chb_location_high_accuracy_key");
    mChbLocationHigh.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(mLocationChangedListener);
    mChbLocationHigh.setOnPreferenceClickListener(mLocationClickListener);
    mChbLocationBalanced = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("pref_chb_location_balanced_power_key");
    mChbLocationBalanced.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(mLocationChangedListener);
    mChbLocationBalanced
            .setOnPreferenceClickListener(mLocationClickListener);
    mChbLocationLowPower = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("pref_chb_location_low_power_key");
    mChbLocationLowPower.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(mLocationChangedListener);
    mChbLocationLowPower
            .setOnPreferenceClickListener(mLocationClickListener);
    mChbLocationNoPower = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("pref_chb_location_no_power_key");
    mChbLocationNoPower.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(mLocationChangedListener);
    mChbLocationNoPower
            .setOnPreferenceClickListener(mLocationClickListener);
}

private void setLocationAccuracy() {
    boolean isChecked = mChbLocationLastChanged.isChecked();
    String key = mChbLocationLastChanged.getKey();
    if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("pref_chb_location_high_accuracy_key")) {
        mChbLocationBalanced.setChecked(false);
        mChbLocationLowPower.setChecked(false);
        mChbLocationNoPower.setChecked(false);
    } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("pref_chb_location_balanced_power_key")) {
        mChbLocationHigh.setChecked(false);
        mChbLocationLowPower.setChecked(false);
        mChbLocationNoPower.setChecked(false);
    } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("pref_chb_location_low_power_key")) {
        mChbLocationHigh.setChecked(false);
        mChbLocationBalanced.setChecked(false);
        mChbLocationNoPower.setChecked(false);
    } else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("pref_chb_location_no_power_key")) {
        mChbLocationHigh.setChecked(false);
        mChbLocationBalanced.setChecked(false);
        mChbLocationLowPower.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (!mChbLocationLastChanged.isChecked())
        mChbLocationLastChanged.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: Set two listeners: OnPreferenceChangeListener() and  Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(). On first listener save to preferenceCheckBox value which has changed. From second get key string value and boolean if checked. Compare, set others to false and if they are all to false give the last changed to true. So it can never be empty selected checkbox.